# UITableViewCell unique identifier?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, deque

I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify instances of UITableViewCells even after they have been recycled (dequeued) via [DequeueReusableCell(string identifier)](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.DequeueReusableCell%28System.String%29) - without subclassing or using a container object.

So basically, when I create a new cell, I want to use a unique id of this cell as a key to store another related object in a dictionary. Later on, when the cell get's recycled/dequeued, I want to read the related objected from the dictionary. *I am totally aware that the recycled cell may be placed at any index path in the table and may (most likely) contain other data than before - the other object really is related to the cell instance, not the index path.*

Loosing relation to the object must be avoided. The obtained id must at all cost be the same that was used when the cell was created.

This was previously achieved by generating a random number and storing it as the cell's tag. However, those tags could collide (when the same random number is generated twice) and I would only want to implement collision avoidance as a last resort. So I'm looking for a better way.

I've looked at [ClassHandle](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.ClassHandle), [Handle](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.Handle) and [SuperHandle](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.SuperHandle) properties. The only one staying consistent among dequeues seems to be the ClassHandle.

Is it safe to use the ClassHandle property for this purpose? If not, what other options are there?

Comment: Out of curiousity, is there a particular reason that you don't want to subclass UITableViewCell? Doing so would most likely make your application much less complex because you could then store any type of reference that you want directly in the cell and not have to worry about it. We created a very simple inherited class that has an Object tag which is very flexible and has worked for every scenario that we have faced so far.

Comment: Both the Android and iOS versions of the app currently use a dictionary to store an additional object for each cell (when required). I'd simply like to stay consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own monotonically increasing number:

```
static int monotonicNumber;
```

and then set the tag to:

```
cell.Tag = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment (ref monotonicNumber);
```

Note that Environment.TickCount isn't guaranteed to be unique, you can get identical tick counts if you fetch it in rapid succession. I know because it has happened to me.

Comment: 1) Why static? Please explain. 2) Would it be ok to simply ++ the number? AFAIK, only the UI thread is going to execute the UI code.

Comment: 1) Why not? It really depends on your code, you can use an instance field too if you know you don't need unique ids across multiple instances of the class. Since I didn't know if you needed that or not I chose the safe option: static. 2) Yes, if it's only going to be used by the UI thread you can use the increment operator ++.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jonathan Pepper's answer, this is a fairly common technique used in numerous examples online:

Whenever you create a new cell in your `GetCell` method, set the cell's `Tag` using

```
cell.Tag = Environment.TickCount;
```

This is especially useful if you have a custom cell object. Your cells can then be tracked in your data source class using a dictionary, for example:

```
Dictionary<int, your_cell_type> cells = ...
```

If you need to track something cell specific, you can use the `Tag` to look it up on your dictionary object.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Here is the original article i got this idea from: http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables

Comment: If you do take this approach, you must be very careful to remove the reference to the cell in the dictionary object so that you don't have a memory leak with a bunch of cells accumulating in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Guid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

These are the standard, proven to always be unique, ids for .Net.  These are available on Windows as well as Mono running anywhere.

I'm assuming the Tag property is an object and you can store it there (but may be an int knowing Apple).  If not, you could subclass UITableViewCell to add a property of type Guid.

Comment: Tag is an int (unfortunately)

Comment: Sounds like you should subclass UITableViewCell for your purposes.  They will still come out properly with DequeueReuseableCell, you can just cast to your new type.